# npm: prevent installation if package contains certain dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

Since there are multiple incidents because of infected npm-packages, I just asked myself if its somehow possible, to prevent the installation of an package, if it contains a certain dependency or if that dependency is somewhere in the chain. Is that possible with npm?

Something really basic in package.json like

```
{
  "prevent":["rc@1.2.9"]
}
```

... or something in that manner